# Macroexpanded form evaluates, but non-expanded form throws exception

Tags: clojure, macros, cider

I'm using CIDER if that matters.

```
(defmacro trace [prompt x]
  (let [p (subs prompt 4)
        expanded (macroexpand x)]
    (cond (seq? expanded) `(do (println ~p '~x "...")
                               (let [result ~(map #(if (or (not (symbol? %)) (function? %))
                                                     (list 'trace (join [prompt prompt]) %)
                                                     %) expanded)] 
                               (println ~p result "->" ~expanded))
                               ~expanded)
          :else expanded)))
```

That's the macro I'm working on, but it shouldn't matter (though it probably does).

This is the specific piece of code that is causing the problem

```
(trace "    " (if true 6 4))
```

Evaluating this straight throws an exception:

```
Can't let qualified name: clj-match.trace/result
```

I macroexpanded the form to debug it and I got this:

```
(do
  (println "" '(if true 6 4) "...")
  (let* [result (if true 6 4)] (println "" result "->" (if true 6 4)))
  (if true 6 4))
```

This doesn't look bad at all, so I tried eval-ing the expanded form.  Surprisingly it worked, evaluating to 6.

Why does this happen?

More importantly, what am I doing wrong to get the exception?

Comment: @Elogent oh, sorry, I didn't copy the last line of the macro.  It's fixed now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second question first: you're getting an exception, because you are indeed trying to `let` a qualified name, specifically `clj-match.trace/result`.

This happens because your syntax-quoted `(do …)` form that the macro expands into in the `seq?` case uses `result` as the name of the local binding in the `let` form it produces. That literal `result` symbol will be namespace-qualified by the reader, because it occurs inside a syntax-quoted form, and so the end result will be `(let [clj-match.trace/result …] …)`, which is incorrect (names of `let` bindings must not be namespace-qualified). You can use `result#` to avoid this, or else explicitly `gensym` a symbol outside the syntax-quoted form and unquote to use it.

(Incidentally, you may want to syntax-quote, rather than merely quote, your `trace` symbol in the expansion in order to ensure that it actually refers to your macro regardless of the context in which the expansion takes place.)

As for your experiment with expanding the macro – a regular `macroexpand-1` call with your form as an argument will reveal the above, so presumably you used some facility provided by CIDER or another Emacs package to expand it inline? It may be that that facility is somehow buggy.

Comment: You're right that I used CIDER to macroexpand it. It must be a bug with them.

Answer (score 2):

The ` reader macro expands all symbols inside its body to be namespace qualified.

```
user=> (macroexpand `(let [a 0] a))
(let* [user/a 0] user/a)
```

`user/a` is not a valid local binding.

The solution is to use the gensym shorthand feature of `.

```
user=> (macroexpand `(let [a# 0] a#))
(let* [a__3__auto__ 0] a__3__auto__)
```

This is harder for a human to read, but actually generates valid code.